# How to verify text present with a special content using Selenium IDE?

Tags: regex, selenium, selenium-ide

How can I verify that some text contains a particular word using regular expressions in Selenium IDE? For example-if our text is

```
 JavaScript Book
```

how can I detect it using

```
 JavaScript
```

with a regular expression?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the question. Are you asking how to check whether a given text starts with "Javascript"?

Comment: No, I'm asking how to check if some given text contains "JavaScript".

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. I've submitted an edit that hopefully makes the question a bit clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions aren't necessary here. Selenium-IDE's `verifyText` command can do this using wildcards, which are denoted by an asterisk (`*`). Example script:

```
open | http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#verifying-page-elements
assertText | xpath=id('verifying-page-elements')/h2 | *Page*
assertText | xpath=id('verifying-page-elements')/h2 | *some text*
```

The first `assertText` passes, while the second does not.

If you do want to use a regex, the syntax becomes:

`assertText | xpath=id('verifying-page-elements')/h2 | regexp:.*Page.*`